# Why are all the "find your friends" Facebook apps not working anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, geolocation, location, gps

All "find your friends" Facebook apps listed here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-ways-facebook-friends-world-map/, do not work anymore. This article was from 2011, but all searches for more recent alternatives have been fruitless.

There is of course the "nearby friends" feature, but it only shows people that have turned the feature on. It does not "crawl" through one's friends list and collect the "Lives in" datum from each person's profile, even though this should theoretically be very possible.

It seems that there is also a SnapChat imitation in Facebook: https://9to5mac.com/2018/10/03/facebook-location-sharing-nearby-friends/, but when I click on "nearby friends" on my phone here in Canada, it only shows the list (not the map). It is possible that the SnapChat-like feature only works in USA (it is also true that you can "send money" on Facebook messenger when you're in the USA, but cannot when in Canada).

So why is it that it is now so hard to find a Facebook App that does what was so easy to do several years ago? I understand privacy policies might have tightened, but if that's the reason for this, what privacy policy is the culprit here?

Comment: My guess would be that it's related to the changes made to the Graph API requiring app approvals: https://techcrunch.com/2018/07/02/facebook-rolls-out-more-api-restrictions-and-shutdowns/

Comment: @jonsca: But out of the thousands of app developing companies out there, not a single one was able to do this simple thing that several apps were already doing (and already concluded that there was a demand for it) 9 years ago?

Comment: Not a clue, sorry.